# collapsing layout min height is not working

Tags: java, android, xml

i have a collapse layout that contains an image, this image must stop folding at a certain height. however not matter what I try, it just doesn't seem to have any effects.

I've tried both java code and xml to no avail. any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
 coladdtoolbar = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.coladdtoolbar);
    coladdtoolbar.setTitle("jam kardan");
coladdtoolbar.setMinimumHeight(140);

 <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/coladdtoolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="140dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
```

Comment: First make sure you have scrollable content like `Listview/RecyclerView/NestedScrollview` below your AppBar with layout behavior set using `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`?

Comment: Also, please post your complete xml to help us get the clear picture..And Is your issue with scrolling not working at all Or is your image completely scrolling up that's the issue?